# list files under a directory excluding hidden files and without going through sub-folders

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

is there a way to list (`NSLog`) file names under a folder (named `downloads` that is located under the documents directory of my app) with the following conditions met:

1) exclude hidden files (such as .DS_Store files)

2) do not search in sub-folders (i do not want the enumerator to be recursive).

thank you so much in advance.

**EDIT:**

3) do not list sub-folders' names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSFileManager's enumeration with options and pass the appropriate flags, which are `NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsHiddenFiles` and `NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsSubdirectoryDescendants`

This is from the docs:
[image]

Comment: using NSDirectoryEnumerationSkipsSubdirectoryDescendants option, still returns a sub-folder name, how to exclude it ?

Comment: You can check if a certain item is a directory using "fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:"

Comment: @JAHelia Your original question does not state that you don't want directories listed. You state that you don't want a recursive listing. You should update your question with this additional requirement.